# Why is my Google Structured Data Testing Tool = Error: Incomplete microdata with schema.org

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

[http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Femfnews.com%2Fshop%2Fglytamins-liver-gallbladder-kidney-detox%2F](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://emfnews.com/shop/glytamins-liver-gallbladder-kidney-detox/)

can somebody help point out the error.
thanks

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question. The link might die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things are wrong with your product schema.  You need to change the itemprop "reviews" to "review".  Most importantly, remove the offer itemprop tag for the $99.  The two marked up prices are throwing Google off.  That will fix your issue and the full rich snippet will appear in the testing tool.

Here's what the page's code should look like: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004ea3334ffd2069dadf6c948c11916

Comment: thanks for citing two (2) mark-ups for the price this solve my issue.